# Append hostname to all lines in a file on a windows remote server using ansible

Tags: windows, replace, ansible

I have a csv file as below.The number of lines in the file might vary.

```
admin_server, id:1, /tmp
admin_group, id:3, /home
user_group, id:5, /root
```

I need to append hostname to every lines in the file. i.e. I need to add a column 1 which will have the hostname.

1st server:

```
server1,admin_server, id:1, /tmp
server1,admin_group, id:3, /home
server1,user_group, id:5, /root
```

2nd server.

```
server2,admin_server, id:1, /tmp
server2,admin_group, id:3, /home
server2,user_group, id:5, /root
```

In linux, replace module was used and it worked fine. But in windows the replace module is not working.Kindly advise.

What i have tried is as below. It doesnt work, it just appends the hostname at the end of the file.

```
- name: Test
    win_lineinfile:
     path: /tmp/testing.log
     line: '"{{ansible_hostname}}"\1'
     regexp: '^(.*)$'
```

Comment: You can't achieve with win_lineinfile module, try template / win_template. win_lineinfile will replace only the last match. https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/2456

Comment: do you have any sample for win_template?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below, as win_lineinfile module replace only the last match.

#### win_template module

```
- name: Create a file from a Jinja2 template
  win_template:
    src: file.conf.j2
    dest: C:\Temp\file.conf
```

#### Change your file.conf.j2

```
{{ansible_hostname}},admin_server, id:1, /tmp
{{ansible_hostname}},admin_group, id:3, /home
{{ansible_hostname}},user_group, id:5, /root
```

If ansible_hostname doesn't work, set the variable in the playbook and try.

Comment: This file is created by another task in the playbook itself, it is not predefined one.The number of lines in the file may vary. If there are n number of lines, I need ansible hostname repeated n times.

Comment: At the time of file creation, you can prefix a placeholder {{host}} in each line and use it. At least I couldn't find any other way in windows host. replace works fine in linux based hosts.